# Rails CSRF token authenticity on Incoming external POST Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, fiware, fiware-orion

My rails application subscribes to an external system POST notifications (named Orion context broker). I manage sending json data & process response (ruby->Orion).

But when a notification request comes in I get the InvalidAuthenticityToken Error **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity WARNING**.

```
I, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.215991 #22189]  INFO -- : Started POST "/machine/listen" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-03 16:56:53 +0000
I, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.221524 #22189]  INFO -- : Processing by MachineController#listen as XML
I, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.221762 #22189]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"subscriptionId"=>"5660745482ef938cd5055ae3", "originator"=>"localhost", "contextResponses"=>[{"contextElement"=>{"type"=>"Printer", "isPattern"=>"false", "id"=>"UM1", "attributes"=>[{"name"=>"temperature", "type"=>"float", "value"=>"110"}]}, "statusCode"=>{"code"=>"200", "reasonPhrase"=>"OK"}}], "machine"=>{"subscriptionId"=>"5660745482ef938cd5055ae3", "originator"=>"localhost", "contextResponses"=>[{"contextElement"=>{"type"=>"Printer", "isPattern"=>"false", "id"=>"UM1", "attributes"=>[{"name"=>"temperature", "type"=>"float", "value"=>"110"}]}, "statusCode"=>{"code"=>"200", "reasonPhrase"=>"OK"}}]}}
W, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.223637 #22189]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
I, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.224191 #22189]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2015-12-03T16:56:53.225189 #22189] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

I understand that the message that is sent back **(Orion->ruby)** does not contain the proper Security Token.

Maybe I could disable ***protect_from_forgery*** but definitly looking for one way to manage authentification between those different services.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like HTTP Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to disable CSRF protection if you know what are you doing! Just make sure you don't disable it for your whole website

Use something like `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in the controller that recives those post request.